# Ranking K coins

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, multiple-comparisons

How to rank coins without using p value?

Comment: If you want to find "the coin most deviating from its null" then you can rank the coins on just pj. Your comments about P-values are somewhat true, but appear to have been taken out of context.

Comment: Your H0 is designed for bilateral testing and your H1 for unilateral testing. Perhaps that's just an oversight. Your professor clearly wants you to think about effect sizes.

Comment: Effect sizes controlled for standard error. That's what you do when you rank the lower bounds of confidence intervals. bigger effect size => higher ranking but larger standard error => lower ranking. Then you have to deal with an additional difficulty that your pj,0 are all different so you need to either rank according to absolute or relative deviation of the lower bound from pj,0

Comment: The one where the bound closest to H0 (thus the lower bound in your unilateral testing) is furthest from H0 (compared to other coins) has the largest confirmed effect at level $\alpha$. Then you need to decide between  absolute or standardized effect sizes.

Comment: Can't you use Bayesian methods? Assume a beta prior with mean $p_0$ for each $j$ and you can get a posterior beta distribution for each coin and take its mean to estimate the coin's $p$ value. This makes a lot more sense than framing it as a frequentist-style hypothesis testing question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "reddit 'best' ranking" strategy, i.e. score each coin using one of the bounds of a confidence/credible interval. Here's a detailed discussion of this strategy: http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html

Concretely, the reddit approach here is (or at least was) to treat voting events as bernoulli trials, so a downvote is a failure and an upvote is a success. Then, they calculate a wilson score interval to find the lower bound of the success (upvote) probability of a particular item subject to the amount of evidence they have. As they get more observations, the lower bound will converge on the mean success probability. This way, if they have two items with with similar observed success frequencies (upvotes/votes) but significantly different numbers of votes, they'll favor the item that has more votes.

Comment: Rather rank the lower bounds and how they compare to the respective pj,0

Comment: Because the larger the standard error, the wider the CI. That happens when you have a small $n$ for a coin compared to other coins. But lack of available evidence should not be confused with a larger effect size, which you would do if you rank on upper bounds.